# Is it possible to word wrap in the Java stack trace console in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I paste a Java stack trace into the Java stack trace console in Eclipse, it all gets pasted as one long line. I didn't find an option to word wrap inside the Java stack trace console.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean right-click -> Properties -> Console -> Fixed width console?

Comment: Do you mean Right click in the console area > Word Wrap?

Answer (score 11):

The currently working solutions in Eclipse Oxygen:

1. Permanently: Right click on console window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console -> "Fixed width console"
2. Temporarily: Right click -> Word Wrap

Comment: The first adds new line signs at the end of the line. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Line Recently I don't use Eclipse, but I strongly remember, there is an option for this, somewhere. The trick with the Eclipse editor configs, that they are a little bit distributed: there are project-specific and workspace-wide settings, there are also settings for all text editor, and there are the settings for all element types in their specific editor.

Comment: @Line Uhm, you are right++ :-) I didn't see them very, very long ago. [So it looks the console by me](https://i.imgur.com/PwTA99i.png). I started an Eclipse only for you :-) Somehow it should work. I checked also the Eclipse config, but I couldn't find anything about it. I suggest to make a new question from it.